# Disable all the Jenkins jobs in a folder

Tags: python, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-workflow

I have a Jenkins folder called "Automated Jobs", which has over 20 jobs. All of them start building as soon as i create a new installer/package. I want to disable all the jobs in that folder. I will be adding more jobs to the folder, so it is very difficult to disable every job manually.
Is it possible to disable the folder and enable it when i am done with all my work?

Comment: AFAIK jenkins doesn't have folders. do you mean view?

Answer (score 0):

You can get all jobs from the folder and then disable them in a loop:

```
def jenkins = Jenkins.getInstance()
def folder = jenkins.getItem("yourFolderName")
def jobs =  folder.getAllJobs()

jobs.each {

  println "Disabled: ${it.isDisabled()}"

  //disable
  it.disable()
  println "Disabled: ${it.isDisabled()}"

}

jobs.each{

  println "Enabled: ${!it.isDisabled()}"

  //enable
  it.enable()
  println "Enabled: ${!it.isDisabled()}"
}
```

Comment: Any idea How to enable all jobs in one go?

Comment: something like
Jenkins.instance.getItem("folder").findAll { it.isDisabled() == true }.each {it.enable()}

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to do recursive folder disabling or enabling(please remove the enable/disable lines based on your need).
Here DEST_JOB_JENKINS_ROOT is the folder name where your jobs need to be altered. e.g: RootFolder1/Folder2/Folder3
removing getAllItems() will perform action in the same folder(no recursive)

**Code:**

```
def jenkinsJob = jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName("${DEST_JOB_JENKINS_ROOT}").getAllItems()
jenkinsJob.each {
    result = it.doDisable()
    println("Disabled job: [$it.fullName]")
    result = it.doEnable()
    println("Enabled job: [$it.fullName]")
    }
```